# taffyDB JSON sample

Tags: javascript, json, taffydb

I took this JSON from the taffyDB.com (I made it a little shorter for space saving)

```
var friends = TAFFY([
    {"id":1,"gender":"M","first":"John"},
    {"id":2,"gender":"F","first":"Kelly"},
    {"id":3,"gender":"M","first":"Jeff"},
    {"id":4,"gender":"F","first":"Jennifer"}    
]);
```

I am trying to use this JSON with taffyDb

```
var friends = TAFFY([{
    people:[
        { "id": 1, "gender": "M", "first": "John" },
        { "id": 2, "gender": "F", "first": "Kelly" },
        { "id": 3, "gender": "M", "first": "Jeff" },
        { "id": 4, "gender": "F", "first": "Jennifer" }
    ]
}]);
```

but I am not having any luck.

Let's say I want to use this code:

```
// Find John Smith, by Gender and name
friends({gender: "M", first: "John"});
```

I cannot get it to work.  It works ok when I don't include the people:[...]

I've tried

```
friends({people.gender: "M", people.first: "John"});
```

but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var friends = TAFFY([
    {"id":1,"gender":"M","first":"John"},
    {"id":2,"gender":"F","first":"Kelly"},
    {"id":3,"gender":"M","first":"Jeff"},
    {"id":4,"gender":"F","first":"Jennifer"}    
]);

// Find all "M" frends, then filter firstname like "John"
friends({'gender': "M"}).filter({"first": {"like": "John"}});

//  Ignores case
friends({'gender': "M"}).filter({"first": {"likenocase": "john"}})

// directly filter
friends(friends({"first": {"like": "John"}});


// output: [{"id":1,"gender":"M","first":"John","___id":"T000003R000002","___s":true}]
```